# Optimize configuration of MySQL for a single user with complex queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, configuration

I would like to optimize MySQL for a **single user** (me). Noone else is connected to the database. MySQL is installed locally on my PC. The data covers around **70 tables with 150 GB of data** in total.
The data is static, so I won't do changes to it (**no UPDATE or DELETE**). I want to analyze the data, so I will run **large and complex queries including SELECT and JOIN** over large proportion of the data.

**Machine:**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Intel Core i7-4800MQ @ 2,70 GHz
- 32 GB RAM
- 2x 512 GB SSD
- MySQL 5.7, INNODB

**What I did so far:**

- Deactivated HyperThreading (MySQL uses only one virtual Core per
  query - CPU usage 12.5% --> 25%)
- Declare primary keys and
- Indexed all foreign keys
- innodb_buffer_pool_size = 25G
- max_connections=10
- Use of InnoDB

**So what can I do to optimize the configuration (not the query itself) for single-user-queries?**

- database engine?
- general configuration?
- better cache all the information of the joins?

**Note:**
Under the current configuration, the CPU usage is the bottleneck because it is on 25% when I run a complex query. As test i tried some huge queries (fetching a lot of data). If I can believe the timing of MYSQL Workbench the duration was only 4 seconds, but after 10 hours of running it couldn't finish fetching the data...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "indexed all primary . . . keys".  Doesn't sound right.  Primary keys automatically get their own index, simply by declaring them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Yes you are right, that is what I meant. Sorry for being inprecise. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MySiam. It is especially good for read-intensive (select) tables. And you should select a large key_buffer_size. But I am not sure about the JOIN performance... Give it a try

Comment: Hmm, i converted everything to ENGINE=MyISAM and did some test. I had a SELECT query with 8 JOINS. With INNODB it took around 20 min and with MyISAM 6 times longer. So this is probably not a solution. Am I doing anything wrong?